# Check that specific field in every element of an array in a json response has specific value

Tags: json, rest-assured, hamcrest

i need to assert that every field "contentType" inside "content" in the following json response contains "VIDEO" as value.

Right now i'm checking the existance of the field with Hamcrest, like this:

```
assertThat(response.then().body("contents.content", everyItem(hasKey("contentType"))));
```

So i wanted a similar approach to test that the value is "VIDEO" and that it fails if it found one that has UNKNOWN or something different than "VIDEO".

```
{  
   "contents":{  
      "content":[  
         {  
            "title":"clip012123",
            "contentId":1231231,
            "contentType":"VIDEO",
         },
         {  
            "title":"clip45637",
            "contentId":8645634,
            "contentType":"VIDEO",
         },
         {  
            "title":"clip0986382",
            "contentId":8457264,
            "contentType":"VIDEO",
         },
         {  
            "title":"clip249413",
            "contentId":37836783,
            "contentType":"UNKNOWN",
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```java
List<String> contentTypes = response.jsonPath().getList("contents.content.contentType");
MatcherAssert.assertThat(contentTypes, Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.is("VIDEO")));
```